# Dynamically creating an associative array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, associative-array

I'm trying to dynamically create an associative array whose values are arrays. My current attempt is as follows but I'm not sure if it is correct or efficent.

```
foreach $line (@lines)                               # read line from a text dictionary 
{
    chomp( $line );
    my($word, $definition) = split(/\s/, $line, 2); # 
    $definition =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ;                 # trim leading and trailing whitespace

    if( exists $dict{$word} )
    {
        @array = $dict{$word};
        $len = scalar @array;
        $dict{$word}[$len] = $definition;
    }
    else
    {
        $dict{$word}[0] = $definition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your entire `if`/`else` can be replaced by `push @$dict{$word}, $definition`. Right now you are copying the array just to compute its length.

Comment: I got the error message `Not an ARRAY reference`

Comment: that's because $dict{$word} doesn't have a value initially, so trying to cast that to an array doesn't work, because it's not an array reference.

Answer (score 2):

pretty sure this works (can't test right now)

```
foreach $line (@lines)                               # read line from a text dictionary 
{
    chomp( $line );
    my($word, $definition) = split(/\s/, $line, 2); # 
    $definition =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ;                 # trim leading and trailing whitespace

    push @{$dict{$word}}, $definition;

}
```

(using unshift instead of push will put the new entry on the other side of the other entries)

Comment: Probably `||= []` may be omitted, thanks to autovivification.

Comment: Looks like you're right.  Updating answer.  I like the curlies around the cast, though, as it makes it very clear what's being done.